# Not able to open Sublime Text from Terminal

Tags: terminal, sublimetext

I have used: ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl ....initially it was prompting Permission denied.
Than I used sudo.

After this, I could see subl in /usr/local/bin

When I type subl .... Sublime Text is not opening

Please help.

Comment: Hi @Sudhs, welcome to StackOverflow! Does running `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` itself work, or do you get a permission error as well? I'd also look at the output of `ls -al /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` to check its permissions

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you used this command to make the symlink:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

This is incorrect, as you are using both quotes and a \ to escape the space in `Sublime Text.app`. Try just using the quotes:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Please keep in mind that you need to run

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl
```

**first** to get rid of the bad symlink.